# Get the accumulated value from column

Tags: c, database, sqlite

I wrote a C code which reads accumulated bytes from a interface but when this interface goes down it resets and I read 0 again and start all over again reading the accumulated data.

I need to get the real accumulated data from this column in sqlite3.

As an example, if I have the following values (in 10 rows in the table):

```
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 0 | N | 0 |
```

I want to sum only 5, 6 and N which are my real accumulated data; the values appear immediately before a 0 entry.

Is there a way to do it with sqlite3 functions only or should I use sqlite3_create_function (https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html)? If create function so, I did not understood what to do in (*xStep) and (*xFinal) functions!

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE SIM_STATS (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, value INTEGER);
INSERT INTO "SIM_STATS" (value) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO "SIM_STATS" (value) VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO "SIM_STATS" (value) VALUES(5);
INSERT INTO "SIM_STATS" (value) VALUES(0);
INSERT INTO "SIM_STATS" (value) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO "SIM_STATS" (value) VALUES(4);
INSERT INTO "SIM_STATS" (value) VALUES(6);
INSERT INTO "SIM_STATS" (value) VALUES(0);
INSERT INTO "SIM_STATS" (value) VALUES(10);
INSERT INTO "SIM_STATS" (value) VALUES(0);
```

Comment: Why is N written as N and not as 10?  Is there any reason not to change N to 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a modern version of sqlite (3.25 or newer; trivial to ensure since you're using C and can just include the sqlite source directly in your project), it's easy to do with the `lead()` window function. Something like:

```
SELECT sum(value)
FROM (SELECT value, lead(value, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS next_val FROM sim_stats)
WHERE next_val = 0;
```

---

(OP edited post to make this irrelevant, but leaving it in for future reference for anyone who stumbles upon it)

You do need a way to specify the order of the rows; without that rows are returned in arbitrary order that can differ from the order they were inserted into the table, depending on the precise query, indexes used, database configuration, etc. Figure that out (Timestamps work well, or maybe an `AUTOINCREMENT` integer primary key) and use it in place of `ordered_term`.

Comment: I have timestamp and autoincrement key

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: then they should be added to the question. We only know what you say in the question and cannot guess anything else.